# Common Custom Option for multiple products in magento1.9.3.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, multiple

Am having a custom option as "message to be displayed on the product" and "Delivery Date" for a product and I want to use this same custom option for multiple products. Is there anyway to use custom option for multiple products or any free extension is available? 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create product attribute and assign the attribute set.

follow the steps to create attribute:

> https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html#gref

Comment: Whether the details will carry out to the cart page if it is done by creating attribute?

Comment: Yes, detail will carry to the cart page